# Space Won't Free Up

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've deleted files (a lot like half a TB) from a Sharepoint Online site and from the second-stage recycle bin, but none of the space has freed up. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following 2 methods to see if the issue can be solved.

1. Change the site collection storage management to automatic.

   1. Go to SharePoint admin center > settings.
   2. Set Site Collection Storage Management to Automatic.
2. Use PowerShell to set the site collection's storage quota manually.

   1. Set up the SharePoint Online Management Shell Windows PowerShell environment.
   2. Run SharePoint Online Management Shell as administrator.
   3. Run Connect-SPOService and enter your SharePoint admin center’s URL and your admin credentials.
   4. Run the following command to change the site collection’s storage quota:

      `Set-SPOSite -Identity <SiteCollectionURL> -StorageQuota 1048576`